# Is there a way to keep dropdown's mouse over state stay on to test css styling in firefox?

Tags: css, xhtml, firebug

Is there a way  to keep dropdown's stay on to test css styling in firefox?

for example : suppose if on this page http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/bones1.html i want to keep dropdown on just to edit and styles in firebug.

Edit: the given link is just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the css:

```
#nav li ul {
    left:-999em;
}
```

On firebug, select the link above the `<ul>`. You'll see the `<ul>` even though it's hidden. Select it, and disable the `left:-999em;` rule:

[alt text http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/7822/firebugdetails.png](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/7822/firebugdetails.png)

Answer (score 3):

Alter the CSS styles so it displays the secondary ul without needing a `:hover`. Alternatively toggle classnames through JS console to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I would assume you know how CSS works after 700 questions related to front end. I would also assume you knew what Firebug was. Just alter the CSS so `left:-999em` doesn't apply with Firebug. You do know how to use Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Search for `left: -999em;` and change it to `left: auto;`.
*PS:* Ln 35